# How to set the list by alphanumerical order?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a folder containing 10 subfolders with the following naming :

Folder1,Folder2,Folder3,...
i want to manipulate them by that order however when i apply

```
lst = os.listdir(dirname)
lst.sort()
```

the output is the following :

```
Folder1
Folder10
Folder2
Folder3
Folder4
Folder5
Folder6
Folder7
Folder8
Folder9
```

which is expected, to sort the out properly  i did the following :

```
lst = os.listdir(dirname)
lst.sort()

projects = {}

for p in lst:
    pInt = re.sub(r"Folder", " ", p)
    projects[pInt] = p
    print(p)

print projects
```

getting the following outcome:

```
{' 10': 'Folder10', ' 2': 'Folder2', ' 3': 'Folder3', ' 1': 'Folder1', ' 6': 'Folder6', ' 7': 'Folder7', ' 4': 'Folder4', ' 5': 'Folder5', ' 8': 'Folder8', ' 9': 'Folder9'}
```

How do i proceed from there to list them properly so my system will access them one by 1 by order

Comment: Do you need a dictionary? `lst.sort()` should leave the list in alphanumeric order, which already is what you want, no need to create that dictionary.

Comment: @PacoH. Lexicographic order doesn't work with `2` and `10`.

Comment: KIndly check that folder 10 is after folder 1 in ranking but it should be last after folder 9

Comment: @EricDuminil oh of course. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sorted` with a custom key. The default one is the lexicographic order, which doesn't work for your purpose.

```
>>> data
['Folder1', 'Folder10', 'Folder2', 'Folder3', 'Folder4', 'Folder5', 'Folder6', 'Folder7', 'Folder8', 'Folder9']
>>> sorted(data)
['Folder1', 'Folder10', 'Folder2', 'Folder3', 'Folder4', 'Folder5', 'Folder6', 'Folder7', 'Folder8', 'Folder9']
>>> sorted(data, key= lambda s: int(s.replace('Folder', '')))
['Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3', 'Folder4', 'Folder5', 'Folder6', 'Folder7', 'Folder8', 'Folder9', 'Folder10']
```

If not every folder is called `FolderX`, you could use this key:

```
>>> sorted(data, key= lambda s: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, s))))
['Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Data3', 'Folder4', 'Folder5', 'Folder6', 'Folder7', 'Folder8', 'Folder9', 'Folder10']
```

An alternative would be to rename your `folderX` to `folder0X`. `Folder02` would then be sorted before `Folder10`.